# Show advertisements by using GCP and selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am making advertisement analysis system on the Google Cloud Platform and I am using Python, Selenium and Chrome driver.

I can get google search result and yahoo search result. But no advertisement is shown.

Here is my code.

```
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument(user_agent_string)
    options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
    display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
    display.start()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

I want to get advertisement information from the result. 
Does anyone can help me?

Comment: What exactly do you men by `get advertisement information from the result` ?

Comment: I want to analyse advertisement information from the foogle search and yahoo search.